# Adjust a given table to a desired number of columns

Tags: tables, siunitx, rules

[image: should look as this]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]} 
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup % localize scope of the next instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. sapce
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
    c *{3}{T{2.1}T{2.1}T{3.0}} }  
\toprule
$N_p$ & \multicolumn{3}{c}{method_1}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{method_2}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{method_3} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7} \cmidrule{8-10}
& {parameter_1} & {parameter_2} & {parameter_3} & 
  {parameter_1} & {parameter_2} & {parameter_3} & 
  {parameter_1} & {parameter_2} & {parameter_3} \\ 
\midrule
10 & 13.6 & 98.4 & 113 & 12.4 & 98.7 & 285 & 12.3 & 98.7 & 411 \\
15 &  8.4 & 99.4 & 135 \\
20 &  6.2 & 99.7 & 140 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I have seen the following beautiful table which suits exactly what I want to create as well. Unfortunately, there is one difference, I have 5 methods in total and only 2 parameter for which I want to fill in values. I'm rather new to tables so I wasn't able to adjust this code-snippet accordingly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the table preamble, replace `*{3}{T{2.1}T{2.1}T{3.0}}` with, say, `*{5}{T{2.1}T{2.1}}` , and `\multicolumn{3}{Method i}` with `\multicolumn{2}{Method j}`, adjusting the number of multicolumns to the number of methods, and the number of `\cmidrule`s .

Comment: @Bernard Shouldn't it be `\multicolumn{5}{Method j}` since I have 5 methods in total? Or am I wrong?

Comment: a hand sketch of the desired output would be helpful

Comment: @Pazu: Yes, sorry for this: I copy-pasted and forgot to change the 3 to a 5.

Comment: @jsbibra done, feel free to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the answer match the sketch

Aditionally -- The `\cmidrule` command of `booktabs` package allows for an optional argument using parentheses `( )` to specify on which side it should be reduced:

```
\cmidrule(r){3-8} \cmidrule(r){9-14} \cmidrule{15-18}
```

would shorten the right end of the first two rules. You can also add an amount in braces, i.e. `(r{10pt})` and select both sides `(lr)`, `(l{5pt}r{10pt})`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs} 
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.8pt}
    \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{Method.#1}}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Table showing Feature 5's Functional Tests}
%       \hspace*{-0.5in}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}\toprule
             Np &
              \mc{1}&
                \mc{2}&
                    \mc{3}&
                        \mc{4}&
                            \mc{5} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
             \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
              \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
               \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
                \cmidrule(lr){10-11}
             & pm1&pm2&pm1&pm2&pm1&pm2&pm1&pm2&pm1&pm2\\                
            \midrule 
            20&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A\\
            40&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A\\
            60&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A&A\\
            \bottomrule

        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```